# Modify XML request on Flask with ElementTree

Tags: python, xml, flask, response

I'm python beginner. What I wan't to solve, is modify POST request(xml via cURL) on Flask. Thank's for anny help.

Simple server code:

```
from flask import Flask, request
import xml.etree.ElementTree as etree


app = Flask(__name__)


@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def r_xml():
    xml_data = request.form['TEST']
    tree = etree.parse(xml_data)
    root = tree.getroot()
    attrib = {}
    element = root.makeelement('NEWITTEM', attrib)
    root.append(element)
    return xml_data
```

cURL request:

```
curl -X POST  http://127.0.0.1:5000/test -d "TEST=<xml><Name1>MyName</Name1><Name2>YourName</Name2></xml>"
```

I get this error code:

```
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument
```

Comment: What do get at the server side? do `print(xml_data)`. Where do you get the error? `OSError` - client side or server side?

Comment: The error is on server side. On client side is this: `<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 3.2 Final//EN">
<title>500 Internal Server Error</title>
<h1>Internal Server Error</h1>
<p>The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request.  Either the server is overloaded or there is an error in the application.</p>`

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling `http://127.0.0.1:5000/test` while the method `r_xml` is pointed by the path `/` and not `/test` (See `@app.route("/", methods=['GET', 'POST'])`)